# why does angular directive disable text filter?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-filter

I am adding a readmore directive to an angular app.  The read-more works great, but try to use a filter for text and it does not interpret the filter string correctly.

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/Tsqkv1nd6CC8e5Kr9pdU?p=preview

Change demo text to the code below to see what is happening:

```
<p read-more>(1) This is a short paragraph.</p>
<p read-more>(2) This is a long paragraph. This is a long paragraph. This is a long paragraph. This is a long paragraph. This is a long paragraph. This is a long paragraph. This is a long paragraph. This is a long paragraph. This is a long paragraph. This is a long paragraph.</p>
<p>(3) {{desc}}</p>
<p read-more>(4) {{desc}}</p>
```

Notice the 3rd and 4th examples use the $scope.desc value defined in the controller in app.js. #3 works. #4 fails. Why?  How to fix?

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) { 
  $scope.desc = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec rutrum vehicula tortor, vitae ornare nunc semper eu. Vivamus varius, eros vel tristique accumsan, libero nulla cursus ante, eu eleifend risus orci scelerisque nibh. Curabitur feugiat, augue ut commodo bibendum, nisi leo porttitor diam, tincidunt auctor tellus ante sit amet nibh. Duis velit libero, aliquam at felis eu, pellentesque mollis mi. Nam a est orci. Ut bibendum sagittis semper. Cras eget arcu non augue mollis aliquam. Ut ut gravida ligula. Nulla imperdiet lacinia mi, nec fringilla mauris interdum at. Phasellus gravida tempor varius. Cras molestie et nulla eget maximus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris aliquet malesuada feugiat. Curabitur fermentum bibendum nulla, non dictum ipsum tincidunt non. Quisque convallis pharetra tempor. Donec id pretium leo. Pellentesque luctus massa non elit viverra pellentesque. Cras vitae neque molestie, rhoncus ipsum sit amet, lobortis dui. Fusce in urna sem. Vivamus vehicula dignissim augue et scelerisque. Etiam quam nisi, molestie ac dolor in, tincidunt tincidunt arcu. Praesent sed justo finibus, fringilla velit quis, porta erat. Donec blandit metus ut arcu iaculis iaculis. Cras nec dolor fringilla justo ullamcorper auctor. Aliquam eget pretium velit. Morbi urna justo, pulvinar id lobortis in, aliquet placerat orci.';
});


app.directive('readMore', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    template: '<p></p>',
    scope: {
      moreText: '@',
      lessText: '@',
      words: '@',
      ellipsis: '@',
      char: '@',
      limit: '@',
      content: '@'
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl, transclude) {
      var moreText = angular.isUndefined(scope.moreText) ? ' <a class="read-more">Read More...</a>' : ' <a class="read-more">' + scope.moreText + '</a>',
        lessText = angular.isUndefined(scope.lessText) ? ' <a class="read-less">Less ^</a>' : ' <a class="read-less">' + scope.lessText + '</a>',
        ellipsis = angular.isUndefined(scope.ellipsis) ? '' : scope.ellipsis,
        limit = angular.isUndefined(scope.limit) ? 150 : scope.limit;

      attr.$observe('content', function(str) {
        readmore(str);
      });

      transclude(scope.$parent, function(clone, scope) {
        readmore(clone.text().trim());
      });

      function readmore(text) {

        var text = text,
          orig = text,
          regex = /\s+/gi,
          charCount = text.length,
          wordCount = text.trim().replace(regex, ' ').split(' ').length,
          countBy = 'char',
          count = charCount,
          foundWords = [],
          markup = text,
          more = '';

        if (!angular.isUndefined(attr.words)) {
          countBy = 'words';
          count = wordCount;
        }

        if (countBy === 'words') { // Count words

          foundWords = text.split(/\s+/);

          if (foundWords.length > limit) {
            text = foundWords.slice(0, limit).join(' ') + ellipsis;
            more = foundWords.slice(limit, count).join(' ');
            markup = text + moreText + '<span class="more-text">' + more + lessText + '</span>';
          }

        } else { // Count characters

          if (count > limit) {
            text = orig.slice(0, limit) + ellipsis;
            more = orig.slice(limit, count);
            markup = text + moreText + '<span class="more-text">' + more + lessText + '</span>';
          }

        }

        elem.append(markup);
        elem.find('.read-more').on('click', function() {
          $(this).hide();
          elem.find('.more-text').addClass('show').slideDown();
        });
        elem.find('.read-less').on('click', function() {
          elem.find('.read-more').show();
          elem.find('.more-text').hide().removeClass('show');
        });

      }
    }
  };
});
```

style.css:

```
/* Put your css in here */

a.read-more, a.read-less {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: blue;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
span.more-text {
    display: none;
} 
span.more-text.show {
        display: inline !important
}
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Angular Read More Directive</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.7/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.7"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl"> 
  <p read-more>This is a short paragraph.</p>
  <p read-more>This is a long paragraph. This is a long paragraph. This is a long paragraph. This is a long paragraph. This is a long paragraph. This is a long paragraph. This is a long paragraph. This is a long paragraph. This is a long paragraph. This is a long paragraph.</p>
  <p read-more>{{desc}}</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please show all relevant code within the question. Questions should be self contained and we shouldn't have to go off site to review your issue. Demos are great but should only support what actually exists in the question itself

Answer (score 1):

As per your current code implementation `readmore` is getting called before the `transcluded` DOM content gets projected on directive template.

In this case you should take use `content` attribute just by saying `content="{{desc}}"`, which will allow to call `readmore` method of directive as `attr.$observe` method will get fired.

```
<p read-more content="{{desc}}">(4)</p>
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/HcrL4CaOe2N1nQZqtmHA?p=preview)

Comment: thank you. that solved the problem. not clear why, though. how would I change it so the original html would work?